# spring boot build as war and include external module

Tags: spring, build, war

im trying to build a spring boot maven project as a War file to deploy on a server.

I have a second project "lib" which contains pojo's to the database and is shared across several projects. The current project i want to build as a war but it does not seem possible to set 
    `<packaging>war</packaging>`
when there is a module defined, it only allows for the type of pom.

```
    <modules>
    <module>../lib</module>
    </modules>
```

My question, how can i build the project as war while keeping the module inclusion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are used in parent pom to define it's child and its `packaging` should be `pom`.

Use dependency instead, if you want to include other project in your application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>lib.project.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
    <version>lib.project.version</version>
</dependency>
```

Where

- lib.project.group.id : Lib project's group id
- lib - Lib projects artifact id
- lib.project.version version of your lib project

*Note: Build your lib project first before building your war project otherwise the build will fail.*

Cleaner way of doing this is to create a parent pom and define both war_project and lib_project as its modules and build the parent pom, that's how no dependency will fail and you will get your loaded war.

Comment: i ended up removing the module inclusion and running a maven install on the lib, then as you said. adding it as a dependency. then after that it would build as a war

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent pom which has the war and jar:

```
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
      <module>jar-project</module>
      <module>war-project</module>
   </modules>
```

In your war project include the jar file as a dependency:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>war-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>jar pfoject</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```